# What is the difference between typing.Callable and callable?

Tags: python

In vscode, when I have not performed `from typing import Callable`, it suggests to use `callable`.

`typing.Callable` is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) as an annotation used for type-hinting in function declarations.
So what is `callable`?

The vscode hover popup shows the following for it:

```
(function) def callable(
    __obj: object,
    /
) -> TypeGuard[(...) -> object]
```

whereas for `Callable` it shows

```
(class) Callable
```

My best guess would be that it has to do with the [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) linked in the `typing.Callable` documentation. Because that PEP e.g. also mentions that `dict` is the same as `typing.Dict`. So, is `callable` exactly the same thing as `typing.Callable`?

If they are not the same, how do they differ and when would I want to use which?

Comment: `callable` is a function that returns a boolean indicating whether its argument is a callable. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable — Nothing to do with a type hint, it's just a bad guess on VSC's part.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Ah, so it is [a builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable). Thank you! Without the idea that it might be that, it won't come up when searching for the docs of it.

Answer (score 0):

`callable` is completely unrelated: It is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable):

> Return `True` if the object argument appears callable, `False` if not. If this returns `True`, it is still possible that a call fails, but if it is `False`, calling object will never succeed. Note that classes are callable (calling a class returns a new instance); instances are callable if their class has a `__call__()` method.
>
> New in version 3.2: This function was first removed in Python 3.0 and then brought back in Python 3.2.

This was pointed out by mkrieger1 and deceze in the comments.